# PHP + MSSQL insert сложного текста

Tags: php, sql-server

Как можно записать текст содержащий, очень много спец символов в БД MSSQL?

часть текста который нужно вставить:

> ("CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.AssignedTo']/OldValue"
> = 'Semen Semen' OR "CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.AssignedTo']/NewValue"
> = 'Semen Semen') AND

Пробовал экранировать ****, пробовал mysql_real_escape_string

Всегда вылетает ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: mysql и mssql "немного" разные вещи. впрочем, в любом случае стоит использовать параметры для запросов, решатся многие подобные вопросы.

Comment: возможно стоит сериализовать эту строку и положить в BLOB, если конечно по данному полю не будет производиться поиск

Answer (score 1):

Что бы не заморачиваться с экранированием предоставьте это увлекательное занятие клиентской библиотеке, используйте PDO и bindParam http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php
Или mysqli и mysqli_stmt_bind_param http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
С последним не работал, но должно подойти.